# Where is Kafka's "The Trial" set?

Tags: german-language, setting, franz-kafka, the-trial

The novel *The Trial* by Franz Kafka contains many deliberate omissions of information: for example, the [main character's surname](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3361/17) and the names of several other characters, the nature of his crime, and **the location of the unspecified city and country in which the story takes place**.

Countries mentioned in the text include Italy (the Italian "business contact" in chapter 9) and Germany (Miss Montag is described as German in chapter 4). There doesn't seem to much to go on, with very few explicit mentions of real-world countries. Is it possible to identify the setting of this book?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sup>This answer is primarily based on Ignace Feuerlicht, "Omissions and Contradictions in Kafka's Trial", *The German Quarterly* 1967, 40(3), pp. 339-350 - available [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/402393?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) if you have Jstor access. All quotes below are from this article unless otherwise stated.</sup>

As mentioned in the OP, there is little explicit information in the text indicating a precise location. However, there are various hints which we can piece together using close reading.

First off, let's note something which may *seem* to be relevant evidence but actually isn't, and which is only apparent from the original German text rather than translations:

> Words, such as *Elektrische* (47), *bloßfüßig*
> (48, 173), *Verkühlung* (223, 238), and the use of *sein* in the perfect
> of *stehen* (90, 224) and *sitzen* (160) point to Southern Germany
> and Austria, but are indicative of Kafka's rather than K.'s country
> of origin.

As noted in the OP, we know that the setting isn't Italy or (more importantly) Germany. But so far this is all negative evidence. What positive indications do we have about where it *is* rather than where it *isn't*?

General cultural indications:

- > K. lives in a country which is at peace and where law and
  > order prevail (12).
- > The phrase *mit keinem Heller bezahlen* (138) and the
  > fact that Captain Lanz greets Miss Montag by bowing to her and
  > respectfully kissing her hand (100) suggest more strongly the old
  > Austro-Hungarian Empire.

Now let's start to get more specific. The following piece of evidence cuts down the possibilities a LOT:

- > K. [...] lives and works in a "capital" (112)
  > where German is spoken, judging from the first names and family
  > names (Elsa, Karl, Leni, Hasterer, Biirstner, Rabensteiner) and
  > from the name of the one and only street mentioned (JuliusstraBe).
- > Many or most of the inhabitants of that capital are Catholics since
  > the Cathedral is Catholic. This excludes Bern, the Protestant capital
  > of Switzerland.

Finally, most specifically of all, here's a quote from chapter 10 of *The Trial* itself (using the David Wyllie translation freely available [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/7849/7849-h/7849-h.htm#Chapter_Ten)):

> The moonlight glittered and quivered in the water, which divided itself around a small island covered in a densely-piled mass of foliage and trees and bushes. Beneath them, now invisible, there were gravel paths with comfortable benches where K. had stretched himself out on many summer’s days.

An island on a river with a park excludes Vienna, Linz, Graz, Salzburg, Klagenfurt, and Innsbruck, but it could fit **Prague** - namely [Kampa Park](http://www.prague.eu/en/object/places/480/kampa) on an island in the river Vltava.

Prague also fits the other clues mentioned above: it was the **capital** of the [Kingdom of Bohemia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Bohemia) within the **Austro-Hungarian empire**, a predominantly **Catholic** region where **German** was an official language. It also happens to be the city where Kafka was born and lived for most of his life, so it makes sense for him to use it as a setting for his book.

> People, very familiar with Prague, recognize
> indeed certain sections of the city, the Kampa Island, the Charles
> Bridge, and especially the Cathedral Square and the Cathedral with
> its silver statue of a saint.<sup>2</sup>

Finally, the Prague theory is also supported by Heinz Politzer's book [*Franz Kafka: Parable and Paradox*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Franz_Kafka.html?id=GNlEAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), which says:

> Together, the
> German Rabensteiner, the Czech Kullich, and the Jew Kaminer
> represent the three nationalities of Prague, which is also the city of K.

### TL;DR: it's set in Prague.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Page numbers are from Franz Kafka, *Der Prozeß*
 (Berlin, 1951). H stands for *Hochzeitsvorbereitungen auf dem
 Lande* (New York, 1953) and T for *Tagebucher* (New York, 1948).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Cited to Pavel Eisner, "Franz Kafkas Prozess und Prag", *German Life and Letters* 1961, 14: pp. 16–25 (in German; [available here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0483.1961.tb00045.x/pdf)).</sub>

Comment: Great answer! I think there is one other possibility, though: a fictional city resembling Prague.

Comment: The silver saint is St. John Nepomuk. The cathedral (of St. Vitus) is surrounded by a largely unbroken ring of buildings known as Prague Castle, which does not look very castle-like but more like just a part of town, so that would seem to have contributed to Kafka's depiction of the title structure in his novel *The Castle,* too.