# What kind of censorship was Dostoevsky avoiding by obscuring place names?

Tags: russian-language, historical-context, fyodor-dostoyevsky, censorship, crime-and-punishment

In the opening paragraph of "Crime and Punishment", two locations, S-- Lane and K--n Bridge, are identified only by their first and final letters.  My translation has a footnote which says that Dostoevsky refrained from using the actual names, Stolyarny Lane and Kokushkin Bridge, because of censorship.  What sort of censorship was he avoiding?

Comment: [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/38ykgs/just_finished_crime_and_punishment_why_are_so/) with the same question, [blog article](https://www.malathronas.com/4814/raskolnikoff-crime-and-punishment-locations/) that mentions "Russian censors" without reason, [Study.com question](https://study.com/academy/answer/why-are-street-names-censored-in-crime-and-punishment.html) which is paywalled so I can't read the answer. Nothing (that I can read) is enough for an answer, though.

Comment: Some more detailed discussions at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-Dostoyevsky-and-Chekhov-write-full-names-of-places) and [LanguageHat](http://languagehat.com/in-the-city-of-n/) (read the comments as well as the main blog post). Might be enough info there to start cobbling together an answer, although most of it focuses on Russian authors' *other* reasons to blank out names, rather than what kind of censorship was imposed. See also [my answer here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1944/17) about the general practice of blanking out place names in literature.