# Why is "the ——— regiment" censored in "Emma"?

Tags: jane-austen, emma-austen

When giving us the history of Jane Fairfax, *Emma* by Jane Austen has this line:

> Jane Fairfax was an orphan, the only child of Mrs Bates's youngest daughter.
> The marriage of Lieut. Fairfax, of the ——— regiment of infantry, and Miss Jane Bates, had had its day of fame and pleasure, hope and interest; but nothing now remained of it, save the melancholy remembrance of him dying in action abroad—of his widow sinking under consumption and grief soon afterwards—and this girl.
> <sub>*Emma*, chapter XX</sub>

In my copy, there is one solid line about the length of three em-dashes instead of the name or number of the regiment.

Why is this censored in this way? If Austen didn't want to specify, why not just write around it - "Lieut. Fairfax of an infantry regiment"? Was this changed at some point in editing?

Why is this censored in this way?

Comment: See [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1944/3003) and its answers for the convention of using a dash to indicate a (pretended) censorship of a name, place, or date.

Comment: @GarethRees Does that mean this question should be closed as a duplicate? What is the convention here, when the questions are about two different works but the answers are the same?

Comment: @MJ713 This is the Literature Stack Exchange and so there is always something specific to say about a technique in the context of a particular work, so there's nothing wrong with leaving this question open in the hope of getting such an answer.

Comment: @verbose - see the Meta question linked above, which happens to be specifically about this question

Comment: Yes, but in this case the answer to that question  is entirely applicable to this one. A fresh answer to this q would simply rehash those points. Unless you can provide a specific example or two where what’s going on with this usage in *Emma* isn’t explained by the answer to that q, it’s the same question and will get the same answer.